# git autocompletions in Fish: how can I disable them or speed them up?

Tags: git, autocomplete, fish

I'm running Fish shell (3.6.0) on Ubuntu. Let's say that I'm trying to run `git add foo/bar.txt` . I type:

```
git add foo
```

and then I press <kbd>tab</kbd> . Now the shell freezes up for a few seconds. Even pressing backspace does nothing.

How can I fix this? Can I disable filename autocompletion for Git? This slowness only seems to happen when I'm trying to specify a file for a git command.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the special autocompletion logic that Fish uses for git, falling back to default autocompletion behaviour. To do that, create an empty file like this:

```
echo -n > ~/.config/fish/completions/git.fish
```

Now if you press <kbd>tab</kbd> after `git add foo/` , it will suggest all the files in that directory. It doesn't distinguish between clean files and files that have uncommitted changes.

I don't know how to fix the issues of the slowness without disabling the specific git functionality.

Answer (score 0):

This exact behavior could be explained if there are a great many untracked files, e.g. a `node_modules` folder that is not git ignored. Try the `git add` tab completion in a clean working directory and see if the slowness persists.